# How to know from variables tu use them in a custom code

Tags: hooks

I know it's a newbie question, but it's take me a lot of time to find a a small code for a small fonctionality.

for example I wanted to make the [address phone field](https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield_phone) required, I didn't know how to know the arrays keys.

```
        <?php
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function organize_address_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, $form_state, $context) {
  if(!empty($element['#addressfield'])) {
    $element['country']['#weight'] = 100;
    $element['phone_block']['phone_number']['phone_number']['#required'] = TRUE;

  }
}
```

I tried devel to find it but without result.

So my question,after finding the good hook, how I can know the variables to use.

Is a general question to help me to learn module development.

Comment: @shawn The code in the question works well for me, I just gave an example to request explanation how I do if want write a similar code.

Comment: If you need to clarify your question, you can go back and edit it again. The original version seemed like you were trying to make the field required.

Comment: @ShawnConn I reach my need by using kpr() and debug() functions. thank you

Answer (score 1):

May be I'm missing something: I don't understand why you want to **programatically** make the field required.

`Required` is not a feature of a field **by itself**, it is an option you can set on its **instance** once it's attached to a node, through the `admin/structure/types/manage/yourContentType/fields/yourFieldName`.

Comment: It doesn't work for address field module, because this module provide complex field.

Comment: sorry my question was edited, they understood me wrong, I won't request to know how to make this field required, but how to know variables to work with when writing code like above. I posted a general question.